# Create PDF bookmarks automatically with ntheorem

Tags: hyperref, pdf, bookmarks, ntheorem

Is it possible to automatically create PDF bookmarks with ntheorem's headers?

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%ntheorem
\makeatletter
\renewtheoremstyle{break}%
    {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
        ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}%
    {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
        ##1\ ##2:\ ##3\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}%
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries\large}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{\medskip}
\theorempostskip{\topsep\medskip}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}[Lorem]
\lipsum[10]
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[Ipsum]
\lipsum[10]
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

I want one bookmark for each exercise environment.

In this example the bookmarks should be called "Exercise 1: Lorem" and "Exercise 2: Ipsum". So generally "Exercise n: Name".

It doesn't have to be with hyperref, I don't mind using other packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The start macro `\exercise` is patched to catch the optional
  argument.
- `hyperref` already sets an anchor for the numbered exercise. The bookmark
  uses this anchor directly.
- Package `bookmark` is added to implement the previous point. Also the bookmarks are updated faster.

Full example file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

%ntheorem
\makeatletter
\renewtheoremstyle{break}%
    {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
        ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}%
    {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
        ##1\ ##2:\ ##3\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}%
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries\large}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{\medskip}
\theorempostskip{\topsep\medskip}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}

\makeatletter    
\LetLtxMacro\old@exercise\exercise
\renewcommand*{\exercise}[1][]{%
  \old@exercise[{#1}]%
  \bookmark[dest=\@currentHref]{Exercise \theexercise: #1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}[Lorem]
\lipsum[10]
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[Ipsum]
\lipsum[10]
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## Extension: Support for exercises without titles

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hyperref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

%ntheorem
\makeatletter
\renewtheoremstyle{break}%
    {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
        ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}%
    {\item[\rlap{\vbox{\hbox{\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont
        ##1\ ##2:\ ##3\theorem@separator}\hbox{\strut}}}]}%
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{break}
\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries\large}
\theorembodyfont{\normalfont}
\theoremseparator{\medskip}
\theorempostskip{\topsep\medskip}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}

\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro\old@exercise\exercise
\renewcommand*{\exercise}{%
  \@ifnextchar[{%
    \exercise@opt
  }{%
    \old@exercise
    \exercise@bookmark{}%
  }%
}
\def\exercise@opt[#1]{%
  \old@exercise[{#1}]%
  \exercise@bookmark{: #1}%
}
\newcommand*{\exercise@bookmark}[1]{%
  \bookmark[dest=\@currentHref]{Exercise \theexercise#1}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}[Lorem]
\lipsum[10]
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[Ipsum]
\lipsum[10]
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
\lipsum[10]
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with additional exercise without title]

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for. Hyperref and bookmark have to be the two last packages, right?

Comment: You can remove my name from your answer -- I deleted it :-(

Comment: @MWin123 Not necessarily. There are many packages, which should be used *before* `hyperref`. But other packages, especially unrelated packages, can also be loaded after `hyperref`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Your updated answer would also work.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: Yes, it works, but I deleted it rather

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Hi, I have a follow up question. I forgot to mention that it was possible to not supply the theorem's name / third argument (see \renewtheoremstyle{break}) and it didn't show the colon. Now it always shows the colon. Is it possible to remove the colon from the header and in the bookmark's name, if the theorem's name is empty?

Comment: @MWin123 See updated answer.