# pdf bookmarks for proof environment

Tags: hyperref, amsthm, bookmarks

I want to create bookmarks for my proof environments. That is I want in the table of content displayed in my pdf viewer (skim), proofs be listed along with my subsections. I have the following set up:

Preamble:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[open, openlevel=3]{bookmark}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{
  \bookmark[level=2, dest=\@currentHref]{#1}%
  \par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
\item\relax
  {\bfseries
    #1\@addpunct{.}}\hspace\labelsep\ignorespaces\newline
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist%
  \@endpefalse
}
\makeatother
```

This does generate bookmarks for my proofs, but roughly half of them are linked to wrong pages.

The definition of environment is from http://www.ams.org/arc/tex/amscls/amsthdoc.pdf on page 11. I only added

```
  \bookmark[level=2, dest=\@currentHref]{#1}%
```

which I took from this post: [Create PDF bookmarks automatically with ntheorem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/310104/create-pdf-bookmarks-automatically-with-ntheorem)

Does anyone know what is causing the bookmarks to be linked to wrong pages?

Here is a sample proof environment from my document.

```
%%% ------------------------------------------------------------------------%%%

\begin{proof}[Proof of Theorem~\ref{thm:single-crossing-v_uaR}]
  \label{proof:thm:single-crossing-v_uaR}
  The claim follows from the monotonicity properties proved in
  theorem~\ref{thm:first-order-monotonicity}.
  
\end{proof}

%%% ------------------------------------------------------------------------%%%
```

I appreciate any help I can get on this.

Comment: They don't have anything to latch the hypertaget onto, try `\phantomsection\bookmark... `

Comment: The `\@currentHref` is usually (only) updated when a counter is stepped by `\refstepcounter` so you may need to define a new counter for `proof` env and step it before `\bookmark` is used. Also please provide a complete example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.